# Why is my PowerPivot gallery not showing snapshots?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, powerpivot, web-part-gallery

after creating a PowerPivot document, my PowerPivot Gallery is looking like the image below.

The red cross message is "An error ocurred while capturing snapshots for this document".

How can I solve this? Is this a common error? How can I get the snapshots to show in the gallery?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem in 2013. After a considerable amount of searching, I found this for 2010: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2361559

It hasn't been fruitful for 2013, but various message boards have reported success on 2010. Hope it helps if you haven't already solved it.

Comment: I had seen before that installing SP1 would fix the problem, but I wasn't able to do it. Fortunately, the article you posted also has a manual workaround: editing the **"ASRGLoader.htm"** file. That worked like a charm! Problem solved in 2010. If you get to solve this for 2013, please post it here as well. Might help other people.